# How can I change my initials in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

In Microsoft Teams, in a meeting, for all logged in users their initials are shown. We're a rather small company but I have common initials and there's another colleague in my company who shares my initials. This makes checking "hey, is whoever already in the call" difficult. I would like to be able to choose my initials, for instance by adding my middle initial, in order to make them unique. Would this be possible? I tried looking in on-line help for the product but it does not provide any pointers.

We're using Teams with Office 365.

I've now added my profile picture which already helps somewhat.

Comment: The best practice is to hover their name(s), or pop open the `Participants` sidebar.

Comment: I have not tried it but it might be possible by changing your email contact information. So instead of  for example "John Doe" as displayed name, change it to "John Something Doe" (also change the first name to be John Something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the initials was already requested on
[Microsoft Teams UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/40168840-give-users-the-ability-to-override-the-initials-ic),
without any result.

The only solution is to modify your display-name.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it's just a missing feature in Microsoft Teams. It's too bad!